# Parser for an bifurcation analysis tool

Tags: c++, parsing, math-expression-eval

So during my thesis I used xppaut quite extensively. In the end there were some minor problems and I decided to have a look at the code, which was just released at github.

So after 30 years of on and off development by Bard Ermentrout, it kind of showed some rough edges [github link to xppaut](https://github.com/miscco/xppaut/tree/master), which I tried to smooth [github link to cleaned version](https://github.com/miscco/xppaut/tree/Cleanup_extern).

So now there were two projects remaining. First automation via the ode files and secondly a new GUI. The first idea required fiddling with the parser which was quite involved. As the GUI work with QT required switching to C++ anyway I decided to write a new parser, that simplifies the code and makes it more manageable.

So here is the parser. The definition of the corresponding ODE file type is given here [ODE doc file](https://github.com/miscco/xppaut/blob/Cleanup_extern/doc/xpp_sum.tex).

The Idea was to first parse the file and remove comments/empty lines. Then handle all "special" objects and finish with those things defined by "key name = expression". The information would be stored in an opts structure, that contains the name, the expression and possible arguments as well as the line in the original ode file.

I also added some exception handling to give the user a better feedback. The full code in a compilable setting can be found here [githublink](https://github.com/miscco/xppParser)

## xppParserException.h

```
#ifndef XPPPARSEREXCEPTION_H
#define XPPPARSEREXCEPTION_H

#include <exception>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

#include "xppParserDefines.h"

/* Different parser errors */
enum xppParserError {
    DUPLICATED_NAME,
    MISSING_ARGUMENT,
    MISSING_CLOSING_BRACKET,
    MISSING_MARKOV_ASSIGNMENT,
    MISSING_OPENING_BRACKET,
    EXPECTED_LIST_ARGUMENT,
    EXPECTED_NUMBER,
    EXPECTED_TABLE_ASSIGNMENT,
    RESERVED_FUNCTION,
    RESERVED_KEYWORD,
    RESERVED_OPTION,
    UNKNOWN_ASSIGNMENT,
    UNKNOWN_FUNCTION,
    UNKNOWN_NAME,
    UNKNOWN_OPTION,
    UNKNOWN_VARIABLE,
    WRONG_ARRAY_ASSIGNMENT,
    WRONG_MARKOV_ASSIGNMENT,
    WRONG_TABLE_ASSIGNMENT
};

/* Extension of std::exception to accomodate the parsers need */
class xppParserException : public std::exception {
private:
    std::string m_msg;
public:
    explicit xppParserException(const xppParserError msgType,
                                const lineNumber line,
                                const size_t pos)
    {
        switch (msgType) {
        case DUPLICATED_NAME:
            m_msg = std::string("Name has already been reserved");
            break;
        case MISSING_ARGUMENT:
            m_msg = std::string("Cannot find function argument");
            break;
        case MISSING_CLOSING_BRACKET:
            m_msg = std::string("Cannot find closing bracket");
            break;
        case MISSING_MARKOV_ASSIGNMENT:
            m_msg = std::string("Missing assignment of markov transition probability");
            break;
        case MISSING_OPENING_BRACKET:
            m_msg = std::string("Cannot find opening bracket");
            break;
        case EXPECTED_LIST_ARGUMENT:
            m_msg = std::string("Missing argument in list");
            break;
        case EXPECTED_NUMBER:
            m_msg = std::string("Cannot parse number");
            break;
        case EXPECTED_TABLE_ASSIGNMENT:
            m_msg = std::string("Missing value for the lookup table");
            break;
        case RESERVED_FUNCTION:
            m_msg = std::string("Given function name is reserved");
            break;
        case RESERVED_KEYWORD:
            m_msg = std::string("Given name is a reserved keyword");
            break;
        case RESERVED_OPTION:
            m_msg = std::string("Given name is a reserved option");
            break;
        case UNKNOWN_ASSIGNMENT:
            m_msg = std::string("Unknown assignment");
            break;
        case UNKNOWN_FUNCTION:
            m_msg = std::string("Unknown function in expression");
            break;
        case UNKNOWN_NAME:
            m_msg = std::string("Unknown name in expression");
            break;
        case UNKNOWN_OPTION:
            m_msg = std::string("Unknown option choosen");
            break;
        case UNKNOWN_VARIABLE:
            m_msg = std::string("Unknown variable for initial condition");
            break;
        case WRONG_ARRAY_ASSIGNMENT:
            m_msg = std::string("Wrong array assignment");
            break;
        case WRONG_MARKOV_ASSIGNMENT:
            m_msg = std::string("Superflous assignment of markov transition probability");
            break;
        case WRONG_TABLE_ASSIGNMENT:
            m_msg = std::string("Wrong assignment of table expression");
            break;
        }
        m_msg += " in line " + std::to_string(line.second) + ":\n";
        m_msg += line.first + "\n";
        m_msg += std::string(pos, ' ') + "^\n";
    }

    virtual const char* what() const throw()
    {
        return m_msg.c_str();
    }
};

#endif // XPPPARSEREXCEPTION_H
```

## xppParserDefines.h

```
#ifndef XPPPARSERDEFINES_H
#define XPPPARSERDEFINES_H

#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

/* Basic structure that contains the textual information of an expression*/
struct opts {
    unsigned                    Line;
    std::string                 Name;
    std::string                 Expr;
    std::vector<std::string>    Args;

    explicit opts () {}
    explicit opts (const unsigned line) : Line(line) {}
    explicit opts (const opts &opt)
        : Line(opt.Line), Name(opt.Name), Expr(opt.Expr), Args(opt.Args) {}
};

/* Array of opts structures */
typedef std::vector<opts> optsArray;

/* Array of strings */
typedef std::vector<std::string> stringList;

/* Pair containing a parsed line and the original line number in the ode file.
 * This is mainly usefull for debugging if an error is thrown.
 */
typedef std::pair<std::string, unsigned> lineNumber;

/* Vector containing the keywords utilized by xppaut. We cannot use a set here,
 * as that would change the ordering of the symbols
 */
static const std::vector<std::string> xppKeywords = {
    "!",
    "(t+1)",
    "'",
    "/dt",
    "(t)",
    "volt",
    // "markov", /* Handled separately */
    "aux",
    "par",
    "number",
    "(",
    //"table",  /* This is handeled separately */
    //"wiener", /* Handled separately */
    //"global",
    "init",
    "(0)",
    "bdry",
    "0=",
    "solve",
    "special",
    "set",
    "@",
    "export"
};

/* Set of the valid mathematical operators */
static const std::set<std::string> xppOperators {
    "+",
    "-",
    "*",
    "/",
    "^",
    "**"
};

/* Set of the reserved function names */
static const std::set<std::string> xppReservedNames {
    "sin",
    "cos",
    "tan",
    "atan",
    "atan2",
    "sinh",
    "cosh",
    "tanh",
    "exp",
    "delay",
    "ln",
    "log",
    "log10",
    "t",
    "pi",
    "if",
    "then",
    "else",
    "asin",
    "acos",
    "heav",
    "sign",
    "mod",
    "flr",
    "ran",
    "abs",
    "del_shft",
    "max",
    "min",
    "normal",
    "besselj",
    "bessely",
    "besseli",
    "erf",
    "erfc",
    "poisson",
    "lgamma",
    "shift",
    "sum",
    "int",
    "not"
};

/* Set of the options that can be modified in an ode file */
static const std::set<std::string> xppOptionNames {
    "MAXSTOR",
    "BACK",
    "SMALL",
    "BIG",
    "SMC",
    "UMC",
    "XNC",
    "YNC",
    "OUTPUT",
    "BUT",
    "LT",
    "XP",
    "YP",
    "ZP",
    "NPLOT",
    "XP2",
    "YP2",
    "ZP2",
    "AXES",
    "PHI",
    "THETA",
    "XLO",
    "YLO",
    "XHI",
    "YHI",
    "XMAX",
    "XMIN",
    "YMAX",
    "YMIN",
    "ZMAX",
    "ZMIN",
    "SEED",
    "TOTAL",
    "DT",
    "NJMP",
    "NOUT",
    "T0",
    "TRANS",
    "NMESH",
    "BANDUP",
    "BANDLO",
    "METH",
    "DTMIN",
    "DTMAX",
    "VMAXPTS",
    "JAC_EPS",
    "NEWT_TOL",
    "NEWT_ITER",
    "ATOLER",
    "TOLER",
    "BOUND",
    "DELAY",
    "AUTOEVAL",
    "POIMAP",
    "POIVAR",
    "POIPLN",
    "POISGN",
    "POISTOP",
    "RANGE",
    "RANGEOVER",
    "RANGESTEP",
    "RANGELOW",
    "RANGEHIGH",
    "RANGERESET",
    "RANGEOLDIC",
    "TOR_PER",
    "FOLD",
    "NTST",
    "NMAX",
    "NPR",
    "DSMIN",
    "DSMAX",
    "DS",
    "EPSS",
    "EPSL",
    "EPSU",
    "PARMIN",
    "PARMAX",
    "NORMMIN",
    "NORMMAX",
    "AUTOXMIN",
    "AUTOXMAX",
    "AUTOYMIN",
    "AUTOYMAX",
    "AUTOVAR",
    "BELL",
    "COLORMAP"
};

#endif // XPPPARSERDEFINES_H
```

## xppParser.h

```
#ifndef XPPPARSER_H
#define XPPPARSER_H
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <set>
#include <stack>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

#include "mpParser.h"
#include "mpDefines.h"

#include "keywordTrie.hpp"
#include "xppParserDefines.h"
#include "xppParserException.h"

class xppParser {
public:
    xppParser(std::string fn);
    xppParser(const xppParser &parser);

private:
    void expandArrays       (void);
    void expandArrayLines   (std::vector<lineNumber> &lines,
                             const std::vector<lineNumber> &expressions,
                             const int idx);
    void extractDefinition  (void);
    void extractExport      (void);
    void extractGlobal      (void);
    void extractMarkov      (void);
    void extractTable       (void);
    void extractWiener      (void);
    void initializeTries    (void);
    void readFile           (void);
    void removeComments     (void);
    void removeWhitespace   (void);
    void summarizeOde       (void);

    /* Helper functions */
    void checkBrackets      (void);
    void checkName          (const std::string &name, const lineNumber &line, size_t pos);

    stringList  getList     (const std::string &line, unsigned ln,
                             const std::string &closure, const std::string &delim);
    std::string getNextExpr (const lineNumber &line, size_t &pos1,size_t &pos2);
    std::string getNextWord (const lineNumber &line, size_t &pos1,size_t &pos2);

    bool isNumeric          (const std::string &str);

    keywordTrie::result keywordSearch(const std::string &key,
                                      const char &character);

    /* Filename of the ode file */
    const std::string       fileName;

    /* Vector containing the individual lines from the ode file */
    std::vector<lineNumber> lines;

    /* Trie of xpp keyword */
    keywordTrie::trie       keywords;

    /* Trie of xpp options */
    keywordTrie::trie       options;

    /* Trie of reserved names */
    keywordTrie::trie       reservedNames;

    /* Trie of the already used names */
    keywordTrie::trie       usedNames;

    /* Options arrays */
    optsArray Algebraic;
    optsArray Auxiliar;
    optsArray Boundaries;
    optsArray Constants;
    optsArray Equations;
    optsArray Exports;
    optsArray Functions;
    optsArray Globals;
    optsArray InitConds;
    optsArray Temporaries;
    optsArray Markovs;
    optsArray Numbers;
    optsArray Options;
    optsArray Parameters;
    optsArray Special;
    optsArray Sets;
    optsArray Tables;
    optsArray Volterra;
    opts      Wieners;

    friend class xppEvaluator;
};

#endif // XPPPARSER_H
```

## xppParser.cpp

```
#include <xppParser.h>

/**
 * @brief xppParser::xppParser Default constructor of the parser object
 *
 * @param fn string representing the file name of the ode file
 *
 * This constructs the parser object of a given ode file. First unneeded
 * content is discarded, and a basic correctness check is don. Later arrays are
 * expanded and special constructs like markov processes and tables are handled.
 * Finally, the different keywords are parsed and put into the opts arrays.
 */
xppParser::xppParser(std::string fn)
    : fileName(fn)
{
    try {
        /* Initially read in the ode file */
        readFile();

        /* Initialize the keyword tries for command parsing */
        initializeTries();

        /* Check for incorrect brackets */
        checkBrackets();

        /* Remove all comments */
        removeComments();

        /* Remove unnecessary whitespaces */
        removeWhitespace();

        /* Expand array descriptions */
        expandArrays();

        /* Extract exports to dlls */
        extractExport();

        /* Extract markov processes */
        extractMarkov();

        /* Extract table definitions */
        extractTable();

        /* Extract wiener processes */
        extractWiener();

        /* Extract globals */
        extractGlobal();

        /* Extract all other definitions */
        extractDefinition();

        /* Catch errors */
    } catch (xppParserException& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what();
    } catch (std::runtime_error& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what();
    } catch (std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what();
    } catch (...) {
        std::cerr << "Unexpected error\n";
        throw;
    }
}

/**
 * @brief xppParser::xppParser Copy constructor of the parser object
 * @param parser The parser object that should be copied
 */
xppParser::xppParser(const xppParser &parser)
    : /* Keyword tries */
      keywords(parser.keywords),
      options(parser.options),
      reservedNames(parser.reservedNames),
      usedNames(parser.usedNames),
      /* Opts arrays */
      Algebraic(parser.Algebraic),
      Auxiliar(parser.Auxiliar),
      Boundaries(parser.Boundaries),
      Constants(parser.Constants),
      Equations(parser.Equations),
      Exports(parser.Exports),
      Functions(parser.Functions),
      Globals(parser.Globals),
      InitConds(parser.InitConds),
      Temporaries(parser.Temporaries),
      Markovs(parser.Markovs),
      Numbers(parser.Numbers),
      Options(parser.Options),
      Parameters(parser.Parameters),
      Special(parser.Special),
      Sets(parser.Sets),
      Tables(parser.Tables),
      Volterra(parser.Volterra),
      Wieners(parser.Wieners)
{}

/**
 * @brief Checks whether brackets are closed properly
 */
void xppParser::checkBrackets() {
    using charPos = std::pair<char, size_t>;
    std::stack<charPos> brackets;
    for (lineNumber line : lines) {
        auto start = line.first.begin();
        for (auto it = start; it != line.first.end(); ++it) {
            switch (*it) {
            case '(':
                brackets.push(charPos(')', std::distance(start, it)));
                break;
            case '{':
                brackets.push(charPos('}', std::distance(start, it)));
                break;
            case '[':
                brackets.push(charPos(']', std::distance(start, it)));
                break;
            case ')':
                if (brackets.empty()) {
                    throw xppParserException(MISSING_OPENING_BRACKET, line,
                                             std::distance(start, it));
                } else if (brackets.top().first != ')') {
                    throw xppParserException(MISSING_CLOSING_BRACKET, line,
                                             brackets.top().second);
                }
                brackets.pop();
                break;
            case '}':
                if (brackets.empty()) {
                    throw xppParserException(MISSING_OPENING_BRACKET, line,
                                             std::distance(start, it));
                } else if (brackets.top().first != '}') {
                    throw xppParserException(MISSING_CLOSING_BRACKET, line,
                                             brackets.top().second);
                }
                brackets.pop();
                break;
            case ']':
                if (brackets.empty()) {
                    throw xppParserException(MISSING_OPENING_BRACKET, line,
                                             std::distance(start, it));
                } else if (brackets.top().first != ']') {
                    throw xppParserException(MISSING_CLOSING_BRACKET, line,
                                             brackets.top().second);
                }
                brackets.pop();
                break;
            default:
                continue;
            }
        }
        if (!brackets.empty()) {
            throw xppParserException(MISSING_CLOSING_BRACKET, line,
                                     brackets.top().second);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * @brief Checks whether a given name is already taken or reserved
 *
 * @par name: The name of the new definition
 * @par line: The original line that was parsed from the ode file
 * @par pos: The position of the name in line
 */
void xppParser::checkName(const std::string &name, const lineNumber &line, size_t pos) {
    keywords.setWholeWords(true);
    if (!usedNames.parseText(name).empty()) {
        throw xppParserException(DUPLICATED_NAME, line, pos);
    } else if (!reservedNames.parseText(name).empty()) {
        throw xppParserException(RESERVED_FUNCTION, line, pos);
    } else if (!keywords.parseText(name).empty()) {
        throw xppParserException(RESERVED_KEYWORD, line, pos);
    } else if (!options.parseText(name).empty()) {
        throw xppParserException(RESERVED_OPTION, line, pos);
    }
    keywords.setWholeWords(false);
    usedNames.addString(name);
}

/**
 * @brief Expand array expressions in ode files
 *
 * This function searches for the array expressions found in ode files, that are
 * marked by "x[start .. end]" for single line or "%[start .. end] ... %" for
 * multi line statements. Every array line is duplicated end-start+1 times,
 * while preserving the original order of lines.
 */
void xppParser::expandArrays() {
    auto line = lines.begin();
    while (line != lines.end()) {
        std::size_t pos1, pos2, pos3;

        /* Search for opening brackets */
        pos1 = line->first.find("[");
        if (pos1 != std::string::npos) {
            /* Search for the closing bracket and the dots between the start and
             * the end indices. The dots are only necessary for single line
             * statements.
             */
            pos2 = line->first.find("..");
            pos3 = line->first.find("]");
            if (pos3 == std::string::npos) {
                throw xppParserException(MISSING_CLOSING_BRACKET, *line, pos1);
            } else if (pos2 != std::string::npos && pos2 > pos3) {
                throw xppParserException(WRONG_ARRAY_ASSIGNMENT, *line, pos2);
            }

            /* Determine the range of the indices of the array */
            int start, end;
            try {
                start = std::stoi(line->first.substr(pos1+1, pos2-pos1-1));
            } catch (std::invalid_argument) {
                throw xppParserException(EXPECTED_NUMBER, *line, pos1+1);
            }
            try {
                end = std::stoi(line->first.substr(pos2+2, pos3-pos2-2));
            } catch (std::invalid_argument) {
                throw xppParserException(EXPECTED_NUMBER, *line, pos2+2);
            }

            /* Copy the lines of the assignment into a separate vector */
            std::vector<lineNumber> arrayExpressions;
            auto line2 = std::next(line);
            if (line->first.substr(pos1-1, 1) == "%") {
                /* Multiline statements end with a line with a single "%" */
                while (true) {
                    size_t endArray = line2->first.find("%");
                    if (endArray != std::string::npos) {
                        ++line2;
                        break;
                    }
                    arrayExpressions.push_back(*line2);
                    ++line2;
                }
            } else {
                arrayExpressions.push_back(*line);
                /* Change the first bracket to [j] to unify expression handling
                 * with the multiline case.
                 */
                arrayExpressions[0].first.replace(pos1, pos3, "[j]");
            }
            lines.erase(line, line2);

            /* Expand the array expressions and insert it*/
            std::vector<lineNumber> arrayLines;
            arrayLines.reserve(end-start+1);
            for (int j = start; j <= end; j++) {
                expandArrayLines(arrayLines, arrayExpressions, j);
            }
            lines.insert(line, arrayLines.begin(), arrayLines.end());
        } else {
            ++line;
        }
    }
}

/**
 * @brief Inserts a given array expression into the ode list for given j
 *
 * @param lines A vector that is to be filled with the resulting lines.
 * @param expressions A vector containing the individual lines of array
 *        expressions.
 * @param idx The index that should be used for evaluation of the expressions.
 *
 * This function takes the array expressions and replaces every assignment of
 * type [...] with the evaluated expression for j=idx. Afterwards the resulting
 * line is inserted into the provided vector.
 */
void xppParser::expandArrayLines(std::vector<lineNumber>& lines,
                                 const std::vector<lineNumber>& expressions,
                                 const int idx) {
    /* Initialize the parser with the variable "j" */
    mup::ParserX parser;
    mup::Value j((mup::int_type)idx);
    mup::Value result;
    parser.DefineVar("j",  mup::Variable(&j));
    for (const lineNumber &expr : expressions) {
        lineNumber temp = expr;
        size_t pos1 = temp.first.find("[");
        size_t pos2 = temp.first.find("]");
        while (pos1 != std::string::npos) {
            /* Evaluate the expression within the brackets and replace the
             * brackets with the result.
             */
            parser.SetExpr(temp.first.substr(pos1+1, pos2-pos1-1));
            result = parser.Eval();

            /* Check whether the result is an integer */
            if (result.GetType() != 'i') {
                throw xppParserException(WRONG_ARRAY_ASSIGNMENT, expr, pos1+1);
            }
            temp.first.replace(pos1, pos2-pos1+1, result.ToString());

            pos1 = temp.first.find("[", pos2);
            pos2 = temp.first.find("]", pos1);
        }
        lines.push_back(temp);
    }
}

/**
 * @brief Extract definitions from the ode file
 *
 * This extracts definitions that are given in the keyword list and are marked
 * by an equal sign.
 */
void xppParser::extractDefinition(void) {
    auto line = lines.begin();
    while (line != lines.end()) {
        /* Search for the first keyword. In most cases it should be the first
         * consecutive string that precedes a whitespace or equal sign.
         */
        std::size_t pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0;
        std::string key = getNextWord(*line, pos1, pos2);
        if (pos2 == std::string::npos) {
            throw xppParserException(UNKNOWN_ASSIGNMENT, *line, pos1+1);
        }
        /* Search for keywords */
        auto res = keywordSearch(key, line->first.at(pos2));

        while (pos2 != std::string::npos) {
            opts opt(line->second);

            switch (res.id) {
            case 0: /* !Name */
                opt.Name = line->first.substr(pos1+1, pos2-pos1-1);
                break;
            case 1:  /* Name(t+1) */
            case 2:  /* Name' */
            case 4:  /* Name(t) */
            case 11: /* Name(0) */
                opt.Name = line->first.substr(pos1, res.start);
                break;
            case 3: /* dName/dt */
                opt.Name = line->first.substr(pos1+1, res.start-1);
                break;
            case 9: {/* Name(args...) */
                size_t pos3 = line->first.find("(", pos1);
                opt.Name = line->first.substr(pos1, pos3-pos1);
                opt.Args = getList(line->first.substr(pos3, pos2-pos3),
                                   opt.Line, ")", ",");
                break;
            }
            case 12:
                break;
            case 13: /* 0=Expression */
                opt.Name = "Initial Condition";
                break;
            case 19: /* Name=Expression */
                opt.Name = line->first.substr(pos1, pos2-pos1);
                break;
            default: /* keyword Name */
                opt.Name = getNextWord(*line, pos1, pos2);
                break;
            }

            /* Check whether the name is already taken/reserved, except for
             * initial conditions, where we check for existence.
             */
            if (res.id != 10 &&
                res.id != 17) {
                checkName(opt.Name, *line, pos1);
            } else if (res.id == 10) {
                if (usedNames.parseText(opt.Name).empty()) {
                    throw xppParserException(UNKNOWN_VARIABLE, *line, pos1);
                }
            } else if (res.id == 17) {
                if (options.parseText(opt.Name).empty()) {
                    throw xppParserException(UNKNOWN_OPTION, *line, pos1);
                }
            }

            /* Get the expression */
            opt.Expr = getNextExpr(*line, pos1, pos2);

            /* Check numbers are indeed numeric expressions */
            if (res.id == 8) {
                if (!isNumeric(opt.Expr)) {
                    throw xppParserException(EXPECTED_NUMBER, *line, pos1);
                }
                /* Check if all function arguments are used */
            } else if (res.id == 9) {
                size_t pos3 = opt.Name.length()+1;
                for (std::string &str : opt.Args) {
                    if (opt.Expr.find(str) == std::string::npos) {
                        throw xppParserException(MISSING_ARGUMENT, *line, pos3);
                    }
                    pos3 += str.length()+1;
                }
            }

            /* Find the type of the keyword */
            switch(res.id) {
            case 0:
                Constants.push_back(opt);
                break;
            case 1:
            case 2:
            case 3:
                Equations.push_back(opt);
                break;
            case 4:
                Volterra.push_back(opt);
                break;
            case 5:
                Constants.push_back(opt);
                break;
            case 6:
                Auxiliar.push_back(opt);
                break;
            case 7:
                Parameters.push_back(opt);
                break;
            case 8:
                Numbers.push_back(opt);
                break;
            case 9:
                Functions.push_back(opt);
                break;
            case 10:
                InitConds.push_back(opt);
                break;
            case 11:
                Volterra.push_back(opt);
                break;
            case 12:
                /* Boundary expressions do not have a name */
                opt.Expr = opt.Name;
                opt.Name = "";
                Boundaries.push_back(opt);
                break;
            case 13:
                Volterra.push_back(opt);
                break;
            case 14:
                Algebraic.push_back(opt);
                break;
            case 15:
                /* Extract the argument list */
                pos1 = opt.Expr.find("(");
                opt.Args = getList(opt.Expr.substr(pos1), opt.Line, ")", ",");
                opt.Expr.resize(pos1);
                Special.push_back(opt);
                break;
            case 16:
                /* Sets are a comma separated list */
                opt.Args = getList(opt.Expr, opt.Line, "}", ",");
                opt.Expr = "";
                Sets.push_back(opt);
                break;
            case 17:
                Options.push_back(opt);
                break;
            case 18:
                Exports.push_back(opt);
                break;
            case 19:
                Temporaries.push_back(opt);
                break;
            default:
                throw xppParserException(UNKNOWN_ASSIGNMENT, *line, pos1+1);
                break;
            }
        }
        lines.erase(line);
    }
}

/**
 * @brief Extract exports to link to procompiled C routines inside xppaut
 *
 * This function extracts the in and out arguments of the respective function.
 * To keep with the other structures the Args vector contains both the input and
 * the output. Therefore the Expr string contains the number of input arguments.
 */
void xppParser::extractExport(void) {
    auto line = lines.begin();
    while (line != lines.end()) {
        std::size_t pos1 = line->first.find("export");
        std::size_t pos2 = line->first.find(" ", pos1);
        if (pos1 != std::string::npos) {
            opts opt(line->second);
            opt.Args = getList(getNextWord(*line, pos1, pos2), opt.Line, "}", ",");;
            opt.Expr = std::to_string(opt.Args.size());

            stringList temp = getList(getNextWord(*line, pos1, pos2), opt.Line, "}", ",");
            opt.Args.insert(opt.Args.end(), temp.begin(), temp.end());

            Exports.push_back(opt);
            lines.erase(line);
        } else {
            ++line;
        }
    }
}

/**
 * @brief Extract a global flag implementing a delta function
 *
 * This function extracts the condition, the sign of the flag and the resets
 */
void xppParser::extractGlobal(void) {
    auto line = lines.begin();
    while (line != lines.end()) {
        std::size_t pos1 = line->first.find("global");
        std::size_t pos2 = line->first.find(" ", pos1);
        if (pos1 != std::string::npos) {
            opts opt(line->second);

            /* Parse the sign flag. For simplicity store it in the name slot */
            opt.Name = getNextWord(*line, pos1, pos2);

            /* Parse flip condition. */
            pos1 = line->first.find_first_not_of(" ", pos2);
            pos2 = line->first.find("{", pos1);
            opt.Expr = line->first.substr(pos1, pos2-pos1-1);

            /* The individual resets are separated by a semicolon */
            opt.Args = getList(line->first.substr(pos2), opt.Line, "}", ";");
            Globals.push_back(opt);
            lines.erase(line);
        } else {
            ++line;
        }
    }
}

/**
 * @brief Extract a markov process from the parsed lines
 *
 * This function extracts the definition of markov processes as they constitute
 * one of the few multiline statements in an ode file.
 */
void xppParser::extractMarkov(void) {
    auto line = lines.begin();
    while (line != lines.end()) {
        std::size_t pos1 = line->first.find("markov");
        std::size_t pos2 = line->first.find(" ", pos1);
        if (pos1 != std::string::npos) {
            opts opt(line->second);

            opt.Name = getNextWord(*line, pos1, pos2);
            checkName(opt.Name, *line, pos1);

            /* Parse the number of states */
            int nstates;
            try {
                nstates = std::stoi(getNextWord(*line, pos1, pos2));
            } catch (std::invalid_argument) {
                throw xppParserException(EXPECTED_NUMBER, *line, pos1);
            }
            opt.Expr = nstates;

            /* Parse the transition probabilities */
            opt.Args.reserve(nstates*nstates);
            for (int i=0; i < nstates; i++) {
                auto line2 = std::next(line);
                pos2 = 0;
                for (int j=0; j < nstates; j++) {
                    pos1 = line2->first.find("{", pos2);
                    pos2 = line2->first.find("}", pos1);
                    if (pos1 == std::string::npos) {
                        throw xppParserException(MISSING_MARKOV_ASSIGNMENT,
                                                 *line2, pos2);
                    }
                    opt.Args.push_back(line2->first.substr(pos1+1, pos2-pos1-1));
                }
                if (pos2 != line2->first.size()-1) {
                    throw xppParserException(WRONG_MARKOV_ASSIGNMENT,
                                             *line2, line2->first.size());
                }
                lines.erase(line2);
            }
            Markovs.push_back(opt);
            lines.erase(line);
        } else {
            ++line;
        }
    }
}

/**
 * @brief Extract a table
 *
 * This function extracts a precomputed table either from a file or calculates
 * it from the definition.
 */
void xppParser::extractTable(void) {
    auto line = lines.begin();
    while (line != lines.end()) {
        std::size_t pos1 = line->first.find("table");
        std::size_t pos2 = line->first.find(" ", pos1);
        if (pos1 != std::string::npos) {
            opts opt(line->second);

            unsigned npoints;
            double xLow, xHigh;

            /* Initialize the parser */
            mup::ParserX parser;

            /* Parse the name */
            opt.Name = getNextWord(*line, pos1, pos2);
            checkName(opt.Name, *line, pos1);

            /* If the table has to be calculated there is a % sign instead of a
             * filename
             */
            std::string fn = getNextWord(*line, pos1, pos2);
            if (fn == "%") {
                /* Get the number of points */
                try {
                    npoints = std::stoi(getNextWord(*line, pos1, pos2));
                } catch (std::invalid_argument) {
                    throw xppParserException(EXPECTED_NUMBER, *line, pos1);
                }

                /* Get the bounds */
                parser.SetExpr(getNextWord(*line, pos1, pos2));
                try {
                    xLow = parser.Eval().GetFloat();
                } catch (mup::ParserError) {
                    throw xppParserException(EXPECTED_NUMBER, *line, pos1);
                }
                parser.SetExpr(getNextWord(*line, pos1, pos2));
                try {
                    xHigh = parser.Eval().GetFloat();
                } catch (mup::ParserError) {
                    throw xppParserException(EXPECTED_NUMBER, *line, pos1);
                }

                /* Parse the defining function */
                mup::Value t;
                parser.DefineVar("t",  mup::Variable(&t));
                parser.SetExpr(getNextWord(*line, pos1, pos2));

                /* Evaluate the table expression */
                double dx = (xHigh - xLow)/(npoints-1);
                try {
                    opt.Args.reserve(npoints);
                    for(unsigned j = 0; j < npoints; j++) {
                        t = (mup::float_type)(xLow + j * dx);
                        opt.Args.push_back(parser.Eval().ToString());
                    }
                } catch (mup::ParserError) {
                    throw xppParserException(WRONG_TABLE_ASSIGNMENT, *line, pos1);
                }
            } else {
                /* Open file for parsing */
                std::ifstream fileStream(fn.c_str(), std::ios::in);
                if (fileStream.fail()) {
                    throw std::runtime_error("Cannot open table file " + fn + "\n");
                }
                lineNumber temp;
                temp.second = 1;

                /* Get the number of points */
                try {
                    getline(fileStream, temp.first);
                    ++temp.second;
                    npoints = std::stoi(temp.first);
                } catch (std::invalid_argument) {
                    throw xppParserException(EXPECTED_NUMBER, temp, pos1);
                }

                /* Get the bounds */
                getline(fileStream, temp.first);
                ++temp.second;
                parser.SetExpr(temp.first);
                try {
                    xLow = parser.Eval().GetFloat();
                } catch (mup::ParserError) {
                    throw xppParserException(EXPECTED_NUMBER, temp, pos1);
                }
                getline(fileStream, temp.first);
                ++temp.second;
                parser.SetExpr(temp.first);
                try {
                    xHigh = parser.Eval().GetFloat();
                } catch (mup::ParserError) {
                    throw xppParserException(EXPECTED_NUMBER, temp, pos1);
                }

                /* Parse the table values */
                try {
                    opt.Args.reserve(npoints);
                    for(unsigned j = 0; j < npoints; j++) {
                        if (getline(fileStream, temp.first)) {
                            ++temp.second;
                            parser.SetExpr(temp.first);
                            opt.Args.push_back(parser.Eval().ToString());
                        } else {
                            throw xppParserException(EXPECTED_TABLE_ASSIGNMENT,
                                                     temp, pos1);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (mup::ParserError) {
                    throw xppParserException(WRONG_TABLE_ASSIGNMENT, temp, pos1);
                }
                fileStream.close();
            }
            Tables.push_back(opt);
            lines.erase(line);
        } else {
            ++line;
        }
    }
}

/**
 * @brief Extracts wiener processes
 *
 * This function extracts the declaration of wiener processes as their
 * definition does not contain an equal sign but only the names of the
 * individual proceses.
 */
void xppParser::extractWiener(void) {
    auto line = lines.begin();
    while (line != lines.end()) {
        std::size_t pos1 = line->first.find("wiener");
        std::size_t pos2 = line->first.find(" ", pos1);
        if (pos1 != std::string::npos) {
            while (pos2 != std::string::npos) {
                Wieners.Args.push_back(getNextWord(*line, pos1, pos2));
                checkName(Wieners.Args.back(), *line, pos1);
            }
            lines.erase(line);
        } else {
            ++line;
        }
    }
}

/**
 * @brief Extracts elements from a brace enclosed list
 *
 * @par line: String we are searching in
 * @par encloure: The bracket type { or (
 * @par delim: The delimiter type , or ;
 *
 * @return Args: Vector of strings of the list elements
 */
stringList xppParser::getList(const std::string& line,
                              unsigned ln,
                              const std::string &closure,
                              const std::string &delim) {
    size_t pos1 = 1;
    size_t pos2 = line.find_first_of(delim+closure, pos1);
    stringList temp;
    while (pos2 != std::string::npos) {
        temp.push_back(line.substr(pos1, pos2-pos1));
        if (temp.back().empty()) {
            throw xppParserException(EXPECTED_LIST_ARGUMENT,
                                     std::make_pair(line, ln), pos1);
        }
        pos1 = pos2+1;
        pos2 = line.find_first_of(delim+closure, pos1);
    }
    return temp;
}

/**
 * @brief Gets the next expression between pos2 and a commata outside braces
 *
 * @par line: String we are searching in
 * @par pos1: Old position. Will be updated to the position after the commata
 * or std::string::npos.
 * @par pos2: Position of the equal sign before the expression
 *
 * @return string: String between pos2 and the next commata outside of braces
 */
std::string xppParser::getNextExpr(const lineNumber &line,
                                   size_t &pos1,
                                   size_t &pos2) {
    pos1 = pos2 + 1;
    /* Search for the next commata outside of brackets */
    std::stack<char> brackets;
    auto it = line.first.begin();
    for (std::advance(it, pos2); it != line.first.end(); ++it) {
        switch (*it) {
        case '(':
            brackets.push(')');
            break;
        case '{':
            brackets.push('}');
            break;
        case '[':
            brackets.push(']');
            break;
        case ')':
            brackets.pop();
            break;
        case '}':
            brackets.pop();
            break;
        case ']':
            brackets.pop();
            break;
        case ',':
            if (brackets.empty()) {
                pos2 = std::distance(line.first.begin(), it)+1;
                it = std::prev(line.first.end());
            } else {
                continue;
            }
            break;
        default:
            continue;
            break;
        }
    }
    /* If none was found copy the whole string */
    if (pos1 == pos2 +1) {
        pos2 = std::string::npos;
    }

    std::string expr = line.first.substr(pos1, pos2-pos1-1);

    /* Remove whitespaces */
    expr.erase(remove_if(expr.begin(), expr.end(), isspace), expr.end());
    return expr;
}

/**
 * @brief Gets the next whitespace separated word after pos2
 *
 * @par line: String we are searching in
 * @par pos1: Old position which will be udpated
 * @par pos2: Old position at which the search startes
 *
 * @return pos1: First position of the new word
 * @return pos2: Position of the first whitespace character after the word
 * @return string: String between [pos1, pos2-1]
 */
std::string xppParser::getNextWord(const lineNumber &line,
                                   size_t &pos1,
                                   size_t &pos2) {
    pos1 = line.first.find_first_not_of(" ", pos2);
    pos2 = line.first.find_first_of(" =", pos1);
    return line.first.substr(pos1, pos2-pos1);
}

/**
 * @brief Initializes the keyword tree from the keyword list
 */
void xppParser::initializeTries (void) {
    keywords.addString(xppKeywords);

    options.setCaseSensitivity(false);
    options.setWholeWords(true);
    options.addString(xppOptionNames);

    reservedNames.setWholeWords(true);
    reservedNames.addString(xppReservedNames);

    usedNames.setWholeWords(true);
}

/**
 * @brief Checks whether a provided string is a numeric expression
 *
 * @par str: The std::string containing the expression
 *
 * @return true if the string is a numeric expression, false otherwise
 */
bool xppParser::isNumeric(const std::string &str) {
    char* p;
    std::strtod(str.c_str(), &p);
    return (*p == 0.0);
}

/**
 * @brief Reads in the ode file and stores the lines in a vector
 *
 * This function reads in the ode file given by fileName, ignoring empty lines
 * as well lines containing only whitespace. Furthermore it trims and truncates
 * all whitespaces.
 */
void xppParser::readFile(void) {
    std::ifstream fileStream(fileName.c_str(), std::ios::in);
    if (fileStream.fail()) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Cannot open ode file " + fileName + "\n");
    }

    /* Parse in nonempty lines */
    std::string temp;
    int lineCount = 1;
    while(getline(fileStream, temp)) {
        size_t pos1 = temp.find_first_not_of(" \t\f\v\r\n");
        if (temp == "done") {
            break;
        } else if (!temp.empty() && pos1 != std::string::npos) {
            /* Remove trailing and superflous whitespaces */
            temp.erase(0, pos1);
            temp.resize(temp.find_last_not_of(" \t\f\v\r\n")+1);
            auto last = std::unique(temp.begin(), temp.end(),
                                    [](char l, char r){return std::isspace(l) &&
                        std::isspace(r);});
            temp.erase(last, temp.end());
            lines.push_back(std::make_pair(temp, lineCount));
        }
        ++lineCount;
    }

    if (lines.size() == 0) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Empty ode file " + fileName + "\n");
    }
    fileStream.close();
}

/**
 * @brief Removes comments from ode files
 *
 * This function purges all standard comments from a ode file. If a line would
 * be comment only it is deleted.
 */
void xppParser::removeComments() {
    auto line = lines.begin();
    while (line != lines.end()) {
        std::size_t pos1 = line->first.find("#");
        if (pos1 == 0) {
            lines.erase(line);
        } else if (pos1 != std::string::npos) {
            /* Check if this is the definition of a convolutional integral
             * indicated by curly braces sourrunding the # sign
             */
            std::size_t subpos1 = line->first.find_last_of("{", pos1);
            std::size_t subpos2 = line->first.find("}", subpos1);
            if (subpos1 == std::string::npos || subpos2 < pos1) {
                line->first.resize(pos1);
            }
            ++line;
        } else {
            ++line;
        }
    }
}

/**
 * @brief Removes unneeded whitespaces
 *
 * This function searches for whitespaces within parentheses or before/after an
 * equal sign and removes those.
 */
void xppParser::removeWhitespace() {
    auto line = lines.begin();
    while (line != lines.end()) {
        std::size_t pos1, pos2, pos3;

        /* Remove all whitespaces between brackets */
        pos1 = line->first.find("(");
        if (pos1 != std::string::npos) {
            pos2 = line->first.find(")");
            pos3 = line->first.find_first_of(" \t\f\v\r", pos1);
            while (pos3 < pos2) {
                line->first.erase(pos3, 1);
                pos3 = line->first.find_first_of(" \t\f\v\r", pos1);
            }
        }

        /* Search around the equal signs */
        pos1 = line->first.find("=");
        if (pos1 != std::string::npos) {
            pos2 = line->first.find_first_not_of(" \t\f\v\r", pos1+1);
            if (pos2 != pos1+1) {
                line->first.erase(pos1+1, pos2-pos1-1);
            }
            pos2 = line->first.find_last_not_of(" \t\f\v\r", pos1-1);
            if (pos2 != pos1-1) {
                line->first.erase(pos2+1, pos1-pos2-1);
            }
        }

        /* Remove trailing commata etc */
        pos1 = line->first.find_last_not_of(",;");
        if (pos1 != line->first.size()-1) {
            line->first.resize(pos1+1);
        }
        ++line;
    }
}

/**
 * @brief Checks a keyword search in case of multiple matches
 *
 * @par expr: The std::string to be searched for the keyword
 * @par character: The character after expr.
 *
 * This sanitizes the keyword search in case we have multiple matches. If
 * multiple keywords were found, the name of the expression contains a keyword.
 * This is only possible if it is either an temporary expression or a keyword
 * that is merged with the name. Consequently remove all other findings. If
 * there were no valid keywords left/found this must be a temporary expression.
 * So create a fake result with and index equal to the size of xppKeywords.
 */
keywordTrie::result xppParser::keywordSearch(const std::string &expr,
                                             const char &character) {
    keywordTrie::resultCollection results = keywords.parseText(expr);
    if(character == '=') {
        auto it = results.begin();
        for (keywordTrie::result &res : results) {
            if (res.id == 0 || /* !Name */
                res.id == 2 || /* Name' */
                res.id == 3 || /* dName/dt */
                res.id == 9) { /* Name(Args) */
                ++it;
            } else if (res.id == 1 || /* Name(t) */
                       res.id == 4 || /* Name(t+1) */
                       res.id == 11) {  /* Name(0) */
                results.erase(--it);  /* Remove Name(Args) */
            } else {
                results.erase(it);
            }
        }
        /* No valid keyword left, this must be an expression */
        if (results.size() == 0) {
            results.push_back(keywordTrie::result("", xppKeywords.size()));
        }
    }
    return results.front();
}

/**
 * @brief Returns the different parsed objects and their definition
 */
void xppParser::summarizeOde() {
    for (opts &opt : Constants) {
        std::cout << "Added constant " << opt.Name
                  << "=" << opt.Expr << std::endl;
    }
    for (opts &opt : Numbers) {
        std::cout << "Added number " << opt.Name
                  << "=" << opt.Expr << std::endl;
    }
    for (opts &opt : Temporaries) {
        std::cout << "Added temporary " << opt.Name
                  << "=" << opt.Expr << std::endl;
    }
    for (opts &opt : Parameters) {
        std::cout << "Added parameter " << opt.Name
                  << "=" << opt.Expr << std::endl;
    }
    for (opts &opt : Algebraic) {
        std::cout << "Added algebraic expression " << opt.Name
                  << "=" << opt.Expr << std::endl;
    }
    for (opts &opt : Auxiliar) {
        std::cout << "Added auxiliar variable " << opt.Name
                  << "=" << opt.Expr << std::endl;
    }
    for (opts &opt : Boundaries) {
        std::cout << "Added boundary condition: " << opt.Name << std::endl;
    }
    for (opts &opt : Globals) {
        std::cout << "Added delta function " << opt.Name
                  << "=" << opt.Expr << std::endl;
    }
    for (opts &opt : Functions) {
        std::cout << "Added function " << opt.Name << "(";
        std::string temp;
        for (std::string &arg : opt.Args) {
            temp += arg + ",";
        }
        temp.pop_back();
        std::cout << temp << ")=" << opt.Expr << std::endl;
    }
    for (opts &opt : Equations) {
        std::cout << "Added ODE " << opt.Name
                  << "'=" << opt.Expr << std::endl;
    }
    for (opts &opt : Volterra) {
        std::cout << "Added differential ODE " << opt.Name
                  << "=" << opt.Expr << std::endl;
    }
    if (Wieners.Args.size() > 0) {
        std::cout << "Added wiener processes ";
        for (std::string &str : Wieners.Args) {
            std::cout << str << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    for (opts &opt : Markovs) {
        std::cout << "Added markov processes " << opt.Name << std::endl;
    }
    for (opts &opt : InitConds) {
        std::cout << "Set initial conditions " << opt.Name
                  << "=" << opt.Expr << std::endl;
    }
}
```

## keywordTrie.hpp

```
/*
* Copyright (C) 2016 Michael Schellenberger Costa.
*
* This code is based on a C-implementation of the keyword trie construction,
* preprocessing and text search by Bernhard Haubold.
*
* Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
* of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
* in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
* to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
* copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
* furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
*
* The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all
* copies or substantial portions of the Software.
*
* THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
* IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
* FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
* AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
* LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
* OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE
* SOFTWARE.
*/

#ifndef KEYWORDTRIE_HPP
#define KEYWORDTRIE_HPP
#include <queue>
#include <set>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

namespace keywordTrie {

/**
 * @brief The node struct containing the information of a trie node.
 */
struct node {
    int id              = -1;       /**< Keyword index */
    const unsigned depth= 0;        /**< Depth in the trie*/
    const char c        = '\0';     /**< Character labelling the incoming edge */
    const node *parent  = nullptr;  /**< Parent node */
    node *failure       = nullptr;  /**< Failure link */
    node *output        = nullptr;  /**< Output link */
    std::vector<node*> children;    /**< Child nodes */

    explicit node () {}
    explicit node (const unsigned d, const char &character, const node *par, node *root)
        : depth(d), c(character), parent(par), failure(root), output(root) {}
};

/**
 * @brief The result struct containing the information about matches during a
 * search.
 */
struct result {
    std::string keyword;    /**< The found keyword */
    unsigned    id;         /**< The index of the keyword in the keyword list*/
    unsigned    start;      /**< The starting position of the match */
    unsigned    end;        /**< The end position of the match */

    explicit result (const std::string &key, const unsigned id)
        : keyword(key), id(id) {}
    explicit result (const result &res, const unsigned endPos)
        : keyword(res.keyword), id(res.id), start(endPos-res.keyword.size()+1),
          end(endPos) {}
};

typedef std::vector<keywordTrie::result> resultCollection;
typedef std::vector<resultCollection>    resultTable;

/**
 * @brief The trie class representing the keyword trie.
 */
class trie
{
private:
    node *root         = nullptr;   /**< The root node */
    std::vector<node*>  trieNodes;  /**< Container of the node pointers */
    resultCollection    keywords;   /**< Container of the result stubs */
    bool caseSensitive = true;      /**< Flag for case sensitivity */
    bool wholeWords    = false;     /**< Flag for result validity */

public:
    /**
     * @brief trie Initializes the trie structure with its root node.
     */
    trie() {
        root = new node();
        root->parent  = root;
        root->failure = root;
        root->output  = root;
        trieNodes.push_back(root);
    }
    /**
     * @brief trie Copy an existing keyword trie.
     */
    trie(const trie &Trie)
        : trie() {
        for (const result &res : Trie.keywords) {
            addString(res.keyword, false);
        }
        addFailureLinks();
    }
    /**
     * @brief ~trie Destructor of the trie that frees nodes from heap.
     */
    ~trie() {for (node* N : trieNodes) delete N;}

    /**
     * @brief addString Insert a new keyword into the keyword trie.
     * @param key The new keyword to be inserted.
     * @param addFailure Flag to signal whether the failure links should
     * immediately be updated.
     */
    void addString (const std::string &key, bool addFailure) {
        if (key.empty()) {
            return;
        }
        node *current = root;
        for (const char &character : key) {
            const char c = caseSensitive ? character : std::tolower(character);
            current = addChild(current, c);
        }
        if (current->id != -1) {
            throw std::runtime_error(
                        "Attempted to add two identical strings to the keyword tree.");
        }
        current->id = keywords.size();
        keywords.push_back(result(key, keywords.size()));

        if (addFailure) {
            addFailureLinks();
        }
    }
    /**
     * @brief addString Wrapper around addString(std::string, bool).
     * @param key The new keyword to be inserted.
     */
    void addString (const std::string &key) {addString(key, true);}

    /**
     * @brief addStrings Wrapper around addString(std::string, bool) to add a
     * set of strings.
     * @param keyList The set containing the keys.
     */
    void addString(const std::set<std::string> &keyList) {
        for (const std::string &key : keyList) {
            addString(key, false);
        }
        addFailureLinks();
    }

    /**
     * @brief addStrings Wrapper around addString(std::string, bool) to add a
     * vector of strings.
     * @param keyList The vector containing the keys.
     */
    void addString(const std::vector<std::string> &keyList) {
        for (const std::string &key : keyList) {
            addString(key, false);
        }
        addFailureLinks();
    }

    /**
     * @brief parseText Parses a text with the trie.
     * @param text The text to be parsed.
     * @return Returns a vector with all matches.
     */
    resultCollection parseText (const std::string &text) const {
        resultCollection results;
        if (text.empty()) {
            return results;
        }
        node *current= root;
        for (unsigned i=0; i < text.size(); i++) {
            const char c = caseSensitive ? text.at(i) : std::tolower(text.at(i));
            current = findChild(current, c);
            if (current->id != -1) {
                if (!wholeWords || current->depth == text.size()) {
                    results.push_back(result(keywords.at(current->id), i));
                }
            }
            /* Process the output links for possible additional matches */
            if (!wholeWords) {
                node *temp = current->output;
                while (temp != root) {
                    results.push_back(result(keywords.at(temp->id), i));
                    temp = temp->output;
                }
            }
        }
        return results;
    }

    /**
     * @brief setCaseSensitivity Set the case sensitivity flag.
     * @param flag The new flag.
     */
    void setCaseSensitivity (bool flag) {
        caseSensitive = flag;
        if (!keywords.empty()) {
            throw std::runtime_error("Switching case sensitivity with existing "
                                     "trie might lead to invalid results");
        }
    }

    /**
     * @brief setWholeWords Defines whether partial matches a valid.
     * @param flag The new flag.
     */
    void setWholeWords (bool flag) {
        wholeWords = flag;
    }

private:
    /**
     * @brief addChild Add a child node to the trie.
     * @param parrent The pointer to the parrent node of the new one.
     * @param character The character on the edge to the new node.
     * @return The pointer to the newly created node.
     */
    node* addChild (node *current, const char &character) {
        for (node *child : current->children) {
            if (child->c == character) {
                return child;
            }
        }
        trieNodes.push_back(new node(current->depth+1, character, current, root));
        current->children.push_back(trieNodes.back());
        return trieNodes.back();
    }

    /**
     * @brief findChild Searches for a child node with given character or adds one.
     * @param current The pointer to the current node.
     * @param character The character that is searched.
     * @param addWord Flag sign to decide whether a new node should be added.
     * @return The pointer to the matching node (possibly after failure links),
     * root or the newly created one.
     */
    node* findChild (const node *current, const char &character) const {
        for (node *child : current->children) {
            if (child->c == character) {
                return child;
            }
        }
        return traverseFail(current, character);
    }

    /**
     * @brief traverseFail Traverse the failure links during a search.
     * @param current The original node.
     * @param character The character that is beeing searched.
     * @return The pointer to the matching node after a failure link or root
     */
    node* traverseFail (const node *current, const char &character) const {
        node *temp = current->failure;
        while (temp != root) {
            for (node *failchild : temp->children) {
                if (failchild->c == character) {
                    return failchild;
                }
            }
            temp = temp->failure;
        }
        for (node *rootchild : root->children) {
            if (rootchild->c == character) {
                return rootchild;
            }
        }
        return root;
    }

    /**
     * @brief addFailureLinks Utilize a breadth first search to generate the
     * failure links.
     */
    void addFailureLinks() {
        std::queue<node*> q;
        q.push(root);
        while (!q.empty()) {
            node *temp = q.front();
            for (node *child : temp->children) {
                q.push(child);
            }
            /* A failure link with just one less charater is the optimum and will
             * never change.
             */
            if (temp->failure->depth < temp->depth - 1) {
                for (node *failchild : temp->parent->failure->children) {
                    if (failchild->c == temp->c) {
                        temp->failure = failchild;
                    }
                }
            }

            /* Process the failure links for possible additional matches */
            node *out = temp->failure;
            while (out != root) {
                if (out->id != -1) {
                    break;
                }
                out = out->failure;
            }
            temp->output = out;
            q.pop();
        }
    }
};

} // namespace keywordTrie
#endif // KEYWORDTRIE_HPP
```